# Testing rails "association"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, minitest, model-associations

User has many profiles.

No issues with testing the parent. I'm stuck with testing its association.

The profile model is:

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name
end
```

And the profile_test file is:

```
require 'test_helper'

class ProfileTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  test "create profile" do
    profile = Profile.new({"first_name"=>"test", "last_name"=>"test"})
    assert profile.save
  end
end
```

When I run the test, it gets a Failure:

```
Minitest::Assertion: Expected false to be truthy.
```

Can anyone please make me clear why Create is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Rails 5, if `belongs_to` association is defined, it's required to have association record.

Your `profile` do not set a `user`, so `profile.save` returns false.